# scrape element using ImportXML with XPath in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: html, xml, excel, xpath, google-sheets

Good Afternoon,

I am trying pull the text in between two react-text with in the HTML of a website into excel or google sheets. I just want the words "book now" in cell b1 if the URL in A1 has this text on their website.

Here is the URL: https://www.facebook.com/CourtyardByMarriottSiouxFallsSd/

And the source code reads as followed:

```
<div class="_58gm">
<div id="pages_actions_pagelet" data-referrer="pages_actions_pagelet">
<span class="_4dlt" id="u_0_3l">
<button data-reactroot="" data-testid="ccta_viewer_unit_testid" class="_4jy0 _4jy4 _517h _9c6 _42ft" type="submit" value="1">
<i alt="" class="_3-8_ img sp_bfiwgCAMT7U sx_3b8ce3"></i>
<!-- react-text: 3 -->
Book Now
<!-- /react-text -->
</button>
</span>
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What did you tried? Did you get an error message?

Comment: Thank you for asking!                                                                                               K so tried:
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='_li']//a")

IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")  
                                                                      =IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='_58gm] /i[@class='_3-8_ img sp_bfiwgCAMT7U sx_3b8ce3 ']//text")

Answer (score 1):

So it is much more difficult to literally extract the react text for book now - but the good news is you can construct an if statement to handle that along with import xml, the other good news is that span tag for the book now button is ONLY in the source code if they do in fact have the option available. (as opposed to it just being a part of the template of the page and always being there)

When that tag is not present - the import xml returns #N/A So using that as a condition you can try:

The three urls I used for testing, which i put in A1,A2,A3 were:

https://www.facebook.com/CourtyardByMarriottSiouxFallsSd/
https://www.facebook.com/QueenAnneHotel/
https://www.facebook.com/CourtyardUSSF

The second url is the only one of the three that does not have the book now option - here is the formula:

```
=IF(ISNA(IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[@class='_4dlt']")),"","Book Now")
```

Sadly arrayformula does not work with importxml so you would have to copy it down but should still be really easy to do

[image]

Comment: OMG your are amazing, yes this makes perfect sense. So pretty much, its finding the source and determining if the word book now falls with in the tag requested. I also want to say, you are very good at describing the errors and solutions. Thanks again!!!

Comment: @AJGeringer Thanks :) If you get a chance can you please "accept" the answer as the solution to your question?

Comment: Hey Aurielle, I really appreciate your assistance, and I accepted this as an answer no worries. I was hoping you could help me understand why, "So it is much more difficult to literally extract the react text for book now ". I would rather learn than have it done for me..... thanks!!